# jupyter: any(x) behaves differently if x is an expression or a variable

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I ran the following code in a jupyter notebook (version 4.4.0 with python 3.6.5).

```
s='hello'
t=['a','b','c']
a=[x in s for x in t]
if any(a):
    print('1')
if any(x in s for x in t):
    print('2')
```

The output I get is `2`, but I expect no output. Why does the second `any` evaluate to true, but the first does not?

Running this directly in python3 via the terminal produces no output. I'm at a loss to explain what is going on. I was working on a larger piece of code and found this inconsistency when debugging.

Below is a screenshot of how it appears in jupyter:

[image]

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks. I suspect something is unusual with my setup. Any idea idea what I should try to see what is causing this?

Comment: Check the contents of your variables

Comment: @MadPhysicist I can reproduce in Python 2.7 REPL but it does not aways appear. I suspect this is due to one of those behavior not defined cases lurking in the above expressions. Specifically, the value of `s` got changed to "a". I can post a screenshot if needed.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Never mind. I found my bug and I suspect something similar might have also happened to the OP. I mistyped `a = [x in s for x in t]` **initially** as `a = [x in s for s in t]`. This changed the value of `s`. And when I typed in the correct expression `a = [x in s for x in t]`, because `s` has already changed, the `any` expression evaluated to True. Because the OP is running in Jupyter notebook, something similar could be happening, especially if those lines are not run in sequence.

Comment: I copied the code from this question directly into jupyter as a single block and got this behavior. However, the behavior is not consistent.

Comment: I'd say you're justified in filling a bug report with the jupyter folks. Close vote rescinded.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks. So you think it's a bug in jupyter and not some weird-but-defined python behavior? (I'm new to python.)

Comment: I don't think there's anything normal about this behavior. The normal command line seems to agree